# How to get the name of failed flink jobs

Tags: apache-flink

Our flink cluster sometimes restarts and all jobs will be restarted. Occasionally, some job failed to restart and failed count increases on the panel. However, it cannot let us know which jobs failed.

When total job count grows, it becomes harder to find out the stopped job. Does anyone know how can I get the names of the failed jobs?
[image]

Comment: Try Flink's web api http://xx:8060/proxy/application_xxx/jobs/overview

Comment: @JiayiLiao it shows the json-formatted data which is shown pretty-formatted in panel. It does not help

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple script for that which will give you the list of job names which have failed.

I am using this command to get a list of failed job.

```
$yarn application -list -appStates KILLED
```

Set up alert when your cluster restarts and post restart check the jobs that haven't restarted and you could have alerts for those as well.